# Codeigniter Load data from 1 table and save it on different table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this issue, I want to fill a form from a variable, what i'm doing right now is  passing **ID** through an anchor on the view, here's the sample

```
//view search
<?php echo anchor('rfi/addNotification/'.$ID,'Add Notification',array('class'=>'add')); ?>
```

This calls a function on my controller

```
function addNotification(){
  $id = $this->input->post('ID');
  $data['results']    =   $this->my_model->addTicket($id);
  $this->load->view('ticketAdd',$data);
}
```

And the model

```
function addTicket($id)
{
     if (!empty($id){
        $this->db->like('ID', $id); 
        $query = $this->db->get($this->Table2);
        return $query->result();
     }else {
        echo 'No results to display';
     }
}
```

But Im not getting any results.
I want to prefill some fields, because later I want to save that data on table1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing the data in anchor like `rfi/addNotification/'.$ID`...you are not PSOTING it ...so the correct way of getting it is, using functions parameter....

try this

```
function addNotification($id){
                 //------^^^----here
  $data['results']    =   $this->my_model->addTicket($id);
  $this->load->view('ticketAdd',$data);
}
```

**updated after comment**

```
function addTicket($id)
{
  if (!empty($id){
    $this->db->like('ID', $id); 
    $query = $this->db->get($this->Table2);
    return $query->result_array(); //<---here return as array...
  }else {
    echo 'No results to display';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, i used a print to see the results but now Im getting this error on my view **Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**. Im using this `foreach($results as $row)`

Comment: that is because you are returning your db datas as object and i guess somewhere you are getting it as array....updated my answer please check

Comment: `Im using this foreach($results as $row)` and i assume your are taking the data after this foreach loop as `$row['something']`;...if yes then updated code should work...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to set the value of an input from an variable?

If the input is in the view you access, you can try using the [parser class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html):

Then this is how you will load your view:

```
$this->load->library('parser');
$this->parser->parse('<your_view>', array(
    'value' => 'your_value'
);
```

And your view will look like:

```
<input type="text" name="some_text" value="{value}" />
```